# Jordan normal form of complex 5x5 Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I'm preparing for my exam and while studying an old exam I came across this exercise. In essence I'm supposed to find the Jordan normal form of the following matrix:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I found the characteristic polynomial with Laplace expansion along the first column (then 2nd then 3rd):
$$
P(\lambda)=(1-\lambda)^5
$$

I got three Eigenvectors out of $\lambda = 1$, those are:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
-6/5\\
1\\
0\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So I'm looking for another 2 vectors since the algebraic multiplicity $m_a(\lambda) = 5$ and the geometric multiplicity $m_g(\lambda)=5$.

We learned that in order to find the remaining vectors if $m_a \neq m_g$, we have to take the power of the matrix we used for the initial Eigenvector(s) and solve it the same way.
$$\Rightarrow
Ker(A-\lambda*I_n)^2
$$

The problem ist, that this matrix is the Nullmatrix, so how am I supposed to find the remaining 2 vectors?

Comment: From the first column you see that the matrix has non-trivial kernel, so one eigenvalue must be $0$, so you made a mistake in your computation of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Your char. polynomial is wrong. It must be $\;t(t-1)^4\;$ . What you want also is the minimal polynomial...

Comment: It helps to notice that your matrix is a direct sum of a $3\times 3$ and a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Realized I made the mistake at the beginning... @V.S.e.H. could you explain how that helps me in this situation?

Comment: Lets say that $A = A_1\oplus A_2$. If $A_1x_1 = \lambda x_1$, then $A\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\0\end{pmatrix} = \lambda\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Another thing to notice is that $A_1$ is diagonalizable, and $A_2$ is similar to a Jordan block via a permutation similarity.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Thanks. Maybe you might help with a follow-up. Assuming $a_{11} = 1$, so my initial calculations were correct, how do I get around the Problem of the Nullmatrix I initially had?

Comment: If $a_{11}=1$, then $A_1 = I_3 + N$, where $N = \begin{pmatrix}0 &5&6\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$, so $N$ is a rank 1 matrix nilpotent matrix. Thus, $A_1$ is similar to a direct sum of two jordan blocks (the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda=1$). What happens when you apply the similarity $STN(ST)^{-1}$ with $S= \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&6\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $T=\begin{pmatrix}1/5&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1/5\end{pmatrix}$?